# typing.Protocol class `__init__` method not called during explicit subtype construction

Tags: python-3.x, protocols, python-typing, abstract-base-class

Python's [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) introduces `typing.Protocol` for structural subtyping, a.k.a. "static duck typing".

In this PEP's section on [Merging and extending protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#merging-and-extending-protocols), it is stated that

> The general philosophy is that protocols are mostly like regular ABCs,
> but a static type checker will handle them specially.

Thus, one would expect to inherit from a subclass of `typing.Protocol` in much the same way that one expects to inherit from a subclasses of `abc.ABC`:

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Protocol

class AbstractBase(ABC):
    def method(self):
        print("AbstractBase.method called")

class Concrete1(AbstractBase):
    ...

c1 = Concrete1()
c1.method()  # prints "AbstractBase.method called"

class ProtocolBase(Protocol):
    def method(self):
        print("ProtocolBase.method called")

class Concrete2(ProtocolBase):
    ...

c2 = Concrete2()
c2.method()  # prints "ProtocolBase.method called"
```

As expected, the concrete subclasses `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` inherit `method` from their respective superclasses. This behavior is documented in the [Explicitly declaring implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation) section of the PEP:

> To explicitly declare that a certain class implements a given
> protocol, it can be used as a regular base class. In this case a class
> could use default implementations of protocol members.
>
> ...
>
> Note that there is little difference between explicit and implicit
> subtypes, the main benefit of explicit subclassing is to get some
> protocol methods "for free".

However, when the protocol class implements the `__init__` method, `__init__` is *not* inherited by explicit subclasses of the protocol class. This is in contrast to subclasses of an `ABC` class, which *do* inherit the `__init__` method:

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Protocol

class AbstractBase(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        print("AbstractBase.__init__ called")

class Concrete1(AbstractBase):
    ...

c1 = Concrete1()  # prints "AbstractBase.__init__ called"

class ProtocolBase(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        print("ProtocolBase.__init__ called")

class Concrete2(ProtocolBase):
    ...

c2 = Concrete2()  # NOTHING GETS PRINTED
```

We see that, `Concrete1` inherits `__init__` from `AbstractBase`, but `Concrete2` does not inherit `__init__` from `ProtocolBase`. This is in contrast to the previous example, where `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` both inherit `method` from their respective superclasses.

My questions are:

1. What is the rationale behind not having `__init__` inherited by explicit subtypes of a protocol class? Is there some type-theoretic reason for protocol classes not being able to supply an `__init__` method "for free"?
2. Is there any documentation concerning this discrepancy? Or is it a bug?

Comment: This issue in the Python bug tracker looks related: https://bugs.python.org/issue44807
...
So we may see some updates to `Protocol`/`__init__` interaction in Python version 3.11.

Comment: This may also be related: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/644

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't instantiate a protocol class directly. This is [currently implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Lib/typing.py#L1113) by replacing a protocol's `__init__` with a method whose sole function is to enforce this restriction:

```
def _no_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if type(self)._is_protocol:
        raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated')

...

class Protocol(Generic, metaclass=_ProtocolMeta):
    ...

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        cls.__init__ = _no_init
```

Your `__init__` doesn't execute because it isn't there any more.

This is pretty weird and messes with even more stuff than it looks like at first glance - for example, it interacts poorly with multiple inheritance, interrupting `super().__init__` chains.