# Subclasses fail to instantiate base class variables with super().__init__() when base class inherits from Protocol

Tags: python, python-typing

Given the following code, I'd expect both `a.x` and `a.y` to be declared during instantiation. When class `P` doesn't inherit from `Protocol` both assertions pass. In the debugger, it doesn't seem that class `P`'s constructor is ever being ran. I suspect this has to do with the MRO in some way, but my main question is whether I can still use `super()__init__()` while still having my base class inherit from `Protocol`

```py
from typing import Protocol


class P(Protocol):
    y: str

    def __init__(self, y: str) -> None:
        self.y = y


class A(P):
    x: str

    def __init__(self, x: str, y: str) -> None:
        self.x = x
        super().__init__(y=y)


a = A("x", "y")
assert a.x == "x"
assert a.y == "y"  # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: Please run the program again because it's running without error on my computer.

Comment: Obviously related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62768327/2442804 .

Comment: I get the expected `TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated` as opposed to any AttributeError.

Comment: `Protocol` isn't meant to provide executable code, only type signatures. It actively replaces `P.__init__` with another definition that prevents (in part) `P` from being instantiated directly.

Comment: You should call ```super().__init__(y=y)``` before ```self.x = x```

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea That's not the problem (though it is generally the right thing to do).

Comment: Take a look at the value assigned to `P.__init__`; it's not the function you defined.

Comment: Thanks all. @chepner and luk2302 were on the money. I'm misusing the role of a Protocol and treating it more like an abstract class (with some implementation detail) than an interface (with no implementation detail). I can resolve this by instead creating a new class that sits between the Protocol and the child class.

Comment: Do you really need another class? The purpose of `P` is just to assert that a class has an `__init__` method that takes a string `y` as an argument, without saying anything about what it *does* with that argument. `A` doesn't have to *subclass* `P` in order for an instance of `A` to be considered an instance of `P`, for type checking purposes.

Comment: @chepner this Minimal Reproducible Example doesn't really get to the heart of the use case unfortunately. In reality I'd like to add a Protocol to (1) ensure devs are adding class/instance variables to the body of the class (it's part of our team convention to do so, Using Protocol will ensure it happens), and (2) to ensure a bunch of abstract classes that aren't part of this example actually have a concrete implementation in all of the child classes. Agreed though, in this example having three layers of inheritance is excessive.

Comment: Subclasses of `Protocol` are used to specify a sort of virtual superclass for use as a function argument, not to enforce any particular class definition. Given the definition of `P`, you can write `def foo(x: P): ...`, and you can pass an argument of any type to `foo`, as long as the `__init__` method of that type takes exactly one `str` argument.

Comment: In other words, a protocol allows for *structural subtyping* , rather than *nominal subtyping* (which is what subclassing provides).

Answer (score 0):

You can not instantiate type `Protocol`:

```
b= P("Y")
```

this would retun the error:

```
in _no_init_or_replace_init
    raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated')
```

see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768327/typing-protocol-class-init-method-not-called-during-explicit-subtype-const)